# Code review of merging several sub arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I came along with this code that merges any number of arrays but havent understood how it works. Can anyone shed some light step by step on the logic behind this?

Thanks.

```
function unite() {
var args = arguments;
var hash = {}; //why do we have to declare an object?
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++) {
    if (hash[args[i][j]] !== true) { //this part onwards gets confusing
      arr[arr.length] = args[i][j]; //i dont understand how arr.length increase for every loop
      hash[args[i][j]] = true;
    }
  }
}
return arr;
}
unite([1, 3, 2], [1, [5]], [2, [4]]);
```

Comment: *"i dont understand how arr.length increase for every loop"* Given `arr = []`, `arr.length` is `0`. So, `arr[arr.length] = 42;` is equivalent to `arr[0] = 42;`. Now the array has an element at position `0`, and `arr.length` is `1`. Hence calling `arr[arr.length] = ...` again would be equivalent to `arr[1] = ...` etc.

Comment: ...although the more common method of adding elements to an array is `arr.push(42)`.

Comment: how did `arr[0] = 42` happen?

Comment: It's just an example.